# I have an interface's method that can't be called

Tags: java, interface, compiler-errors

My class `Cupple` needs to call the method `beStored(char)` of a class `DataIterator` that implements an interface `StorableData`.

Here the code of this interface `StorableData` :

```
package general_classes.cupples;    
public interface StorableData {

    public void beStored(char c);

}
```

Here the code of the implementation :

```
package general_classes.cupples;
public class Cupple<TYPE_OF_ELEMENTS> implements StorableData {
    public void beStored(char c) {

    }
}
```

And finally, here the code of the class `DataIterator` :

```
package general_classes.DataIteration;
public class DataIterator<StorableData> {
    private StorableData root_storable_data;
    public List<StorableData> iterate() {
            this.root_storable_data.beStored(read_character);
    }
}
```

Please note that I didn't write all the lines.

The problem is that the compiler tells me that he "cannot resolve the method `beStored(int)`.

**However, as you can see it, it's actually in the interface. So what's the problem ?**

---

**COMPLETE CODE.**

INTERFACE :

```
package general_classes.cupples;

public interface StorableData {

    public Cupple beStored(int c);

}
```

IMPLEMENTATION :

```
package general_classes.cupples;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Cupple<TYPE_OF_ELEMENTS> extends ArrayList<TYPE_OF_ELEMENTS> implements StorableData {
    private int position_to_insert_element;
    private int number_of_elements;
    private Cupple<TYPE_OF_ELEMENTS> next_cupple;
    private Cupple<TYPE_OF_ELEMENTS> current_empty_cupple;

    public Cupple(int number_of_elements) {
        this.position_to_insert_element = 0;
        this.number_of_elements = number_of_elements;
    }

    public Cupple beStored(int c) {
        Cupple returned_cupple = this;

        if(this.position_to_insert_element > this.number_of_elements) {
            this.next_cupple = returned_cupple = new Cupple<>(this.number_of_elements);

        } else {

            //this.add((TYPE_OF_ELEMENTS) c);
            this.position_to_insert_element++;

        }

        return returned_cupple;

    }

    public Cupple next() {
        return this.next_cupple;
    }
}
```

CLASS :

```
package general_classes.DataIteration;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Reads character per character some given data. Stores the character in a
 * list, after having casted it in the specified type by the way.
 * 
 * @author e1300478
 *
 * @param <StorableData>
 *            the wished type of the reading's returned elements
 */
public class DataIterator<StorableData> {

    private Reader reader;
    private List<StorableData> returned_elements_list;
    private StorableData root_storable_data;

    DataIterator(Reader reader, StorableData storable_data) {
        this.reader = reader;
        this.returned_elements_list = new ArrayList<>();
        this.root_storable_data = storable_data;
    }

    public List<StorableData> iterate() throws IOException {

        int read_character;
        do {

            read_character = this.reader.read();
            StorableData storable_data = this.root_storable_data.beStored((int) read_character);
            if(!this.returned_elements_list.contains(storable_data)) {
                this.returned_elements_list.add(storable_data);
            }

        } while (read_character > -1);

        return this.returned_elements_list;

    }

}
```

Comment: your code is not compiling and incompletely posted....

Comment: The other lines are not pertinent

Comment: "_However, as you can see it, it's actually in the interface._" Actually, I can't see that. I see a method in the interface that takes a `char` parameter, but not one that takes an `int`.

Comment: The lesson is: learn the (primitive) *data types*! Your variable `read_character` seems to be an `int` (implied by the error message) but your method expects a `char`.

Comment: I already change `char` to `int`, nothing changes.

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler really?

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler Please post your "corrected" code which still produces the same exact error and let us run it and see because I am able to make this example and run it fine.

Comment: The entire code is available now.

Comment: The problem has been solved (generic type). Please, could you delete this flag "dupplicate" as it's not, and possibly delete a "-1" ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't really understand why you down vote this kind of question, sure the code is not the best I ever seen, maybe the question is not profound, still when you learn you ought to make conceptual error.
If you are still learning you are bound to make mistakes, even make mistake asking questions. I find this a legit question for someone who is still learning the language.

Comment: Moreover, it's even not a duplicate ... I asked the moderators to judge by themselves, no answer.. Thus I still have -10 on reputation..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that the compiler tells me that he "cannot resolve the
>   method beStored(int).

That simply means that you're attempting to pass an `int` type to the `beStored` method. If you look at the interface definition of this method again you'll notice that you're not obeying the contract that has been set.

```
public void beStored(char c);
```

in the code below `read_character` is most likely an `int` type rather than a character hence the error.

```
this.root_storable_data.beStored(read_character);
```

**Solution**

*change this:*

```
int read_character;
```

*to this:*

```
char read_character;
```

*also change this:*

```
StorableData storable_data = this.root_storable_data.beStored((int) read_character);
```

*to this:*

```
StorableData storable_data = this.root_storable_data.beStored(read_character);
```

Comment: I already, before having created this question, tried to change `char` to `int` but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: i didn't say change char to int... i said int to char.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work with int->char or char->int. I'm going to post the entire code.

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler sure.

Comment: The entire code is available now.

Comment: The problem has been solved (generic type). Please, could you delete this flag "dupplicate" as it's not, and possibly delete a "-1" ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler you can delete your own question if you no longer wish to have it available.

Comment: Not if there are posted answers you can't.

Comment: @takendarkk i see that's how it works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this, in DataIterator StorableData is just a generic type, is not the class StorableData, is the same as DataIterator

The following code would compile.

```
public class DataIterator {

    private StorableData root_storable_data;

    public List<StorableData> iterate() {
            char read_character='x';
            this.root_storable_data.beStored(read_character);
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes. Thank you !

Comment: The problem has been solved (generic type). Please, could you delete this flag "dupplicate" as it's not, and possibly delete a "-1" ? Thank you in advance.